# Anyway to default a generic parameter to a certain type?

Tags: c#, generics

Is there a way to provide a default type for a parameter T of a generic, something like:

```
class Something<T = string>
{
}
```

I know there aren't many strong reasons for this, but I would like to hint the code client which type he should be preferably using.

<strike>Another thing, can I restrict the generic type to a `ValueType`?</strike> I've just seen that you can't, but still, I'd like to know why. Anyone has a clue?

Thanks!

Comment: This is not possible by default.

Comment: Why are you saying you can't restrict a generic type to a value type when nearly every answer here demonstrates just how it's done? (Not via `ValueType`, but by using the `struct` keyword.)

Comment: @stakx I said by default. (Like he tried to - by "default"ing the value.)

Comment: @Vercas, sorry for the misunderstanding, my comment was directed at the OP, not at your comment.

Comment: @stakx Oh, okay. By the way, Bruno, if my answer was good, why don't you click the accept icon? (the checkmark)

Comment: @Vercas... Your answer was good and I was going to accept it, and of course I know how to accept answers.

Comment: @stakx I edited the post before I saw the answers and the compiler doesn't accept ValueType as a clause to where. That's why I've changed the post.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Ok, I suppose you have the class:

```
class Something<T>
{

}
```

Now, you might want another class:

```
class Something : Something<string>
{
    // NO MORE CODE NEEDED HERE!
}
```

---

This is the only and the best way.
So if one uses `Something` he will actually use `Something<string>`.

Comment: This works (fsvo "works", not that I would recommend it generally) because `Something` and `Something<'>` (and `Something<','>` is different still) are two *different* classes (imagine the case of `system.collections.IEnumerable` and `systems.collections.generic.IEnumerable<T>` -- this differs from Java where there is essentially only one "collapsed" type allowed). On the other hand, now you have two *different* types :-)

Comment: Another alternative may be: `using Something = foo.Something<String>;` However the using construct is only available in a few cases (before classes or at top of an outer class before members, etc.) and *isn't externally exposed* as an type/alias.

Comment: @pst I'd use that instead of what I posted, but I thought he might need that way more.

Comment: There are some problems with that approach though. Try casting a "Something<string>" to "Something". You either get a compilation error (if types are known), or a runtime exception (if type checking happens during runtime). That's because "Something" is different than "Something<string>" and actually the former is a subclass of the latter.

Comment: @Saysmaster Unless the cast is overloaded and it fully and reliably copies the identity of the original object.

Comment: maybe i'm mistaken but i don't think you can overload casting from/to base types, no?

Comment: @Saysmaster I very much think so too, actually.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970%28VS.80%29.aspx) you can constrain `T` to be a value type using the `where` keyword

```
where T: struct
```

Class declaration would then look like this:

```
class Something<T> where T: struct {
  ...
}
```

Though `string` is not a value type and you won't be able to use it with such a constraint. Maybe `IComparable` would be better in case you want to also use the `string` type.

As for specifying the default type, I don't believe it is possible.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384067.aspx) keyword to constrain the specific types that can be used as type parameters.

For example, you could your class to only accept generic type parameters where the type implements the `IComparable` interface:

```
class Something<T> where T : IComparable
{
}
```

Or, as you mentioned, you can constrain `T` to be a value type by using `where T : struct`:

```
class Something<T> where T : struct
{
}
```

See MSDN's article on [Constraints on Type Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) for more info. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there is a way to default it to a certain type, but you could put that as a comment in the XML docs. As far as restricting to a value type, you can obtain this behavior by declaring your generic as follows:

```
class MyGeneric<T> where T : struct
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: And +1 for answering the 2nd question :p

Comment: If you want strings, you might need `where T : class` because `System.String` is a class.

Comment: @Vercas - correct or you will get the error: `The type 'string' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Something<T>'`

Answer (score 0):

You need a subclass. Recently I needed something like that, this is my solution:

```
    public abstract class MyGenericClass<T1, T2>
    {
        public abstract void Do(T1 param1, T2 param2);
    }

    public class Concrete : MyGenericClass<string, int?>
    {        
        public override void Do(string param1, int? param2 = null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("param1: {0}", param1);

            if (param2 == null)
                Console.WriteLine("param2 == null");
            else
                Console.WriteLine("param2 = {0}", param2);

            Console.WriteLine("=============================================");
        }        
    }
```

You can call the method:

```
    string param1 = "Hello";
    Concrete c = new Concrete();
    c.Do(param1);
    c.Do(param1, 123);
    c.Do(param1, (int?)null);
    /*  Result:
    param1: Hello
    param2 == null
    =============================================
    param1: Hello
    param2 = 123
    =============================================
    param1: Hello
    param2 == null
    =============================================
    */
```

I prefer to use null default values since i read this:
[C# In Depth – Optional Parameters and Named Arguments](http://codebetter.com/2011/01/11/c-in-depth-optional-parameters-and-named-arguments-2/)